# Error when compiling cardano-node 1.35.5

Tags: cardano-node, cabal, node, spo, ghc

I am getting the following error when trying to compile the new version of the `cardano-node`:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Error: cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: cardano-api-1.35.5 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of cardano-api)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.17.0.0/installed-4.17.0.0 (conflict: cardano-api =>
base>=4.14 && <4.15)
[__1] skipping: base-4.17.0.0, base-4.16.4.0, base-4.16.3.0, base-4.16.2.0,
base-4.16.1.0, base-4.16.0.0, base-4.15.1.0, base-4.15.0.0 (has the same
characteristics that caused the previous version to fail: excluded by
constraint '>=4.14 && <4.15' from 'cardano-api')
[__1] rejecting: base-4.14.3.0, base-4.14.2.0, base-4.14.1.0, base-4.14.0.0,
base-4.13.0.0, base-4.12.0.0, base-4.11.1.0, base-4.11.0.0, base-4.10.1.0,
base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0,
base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1,
base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0,
base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0,
base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from
non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, cardano-api)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, cardano-api
```

I am using `ghc 9.4.4` and `cabal 3.8.1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this error is to downgrade `ghc` to version `8.10.7` by running the following commands:

```
ghcup install ghc 8.10.7
ghcup set ghc 8.10.7
```

Then, you have to prepare the compilation for that specific compiler version, like this:

```
cabal configure -O0 -w ghc-8.10.7
```

Then you can run:

```
cabal build cardano-node cardano-cli
```

Unfortunately, `cardano-node` is not yet compatible with the latests versions of `ghc` (`9.4.4` and `9.2.5` at the time of this post).